# How to group By dates and get the counts in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to group by the documents based on the date and get the counts for the date. my aggregate query below,
while i try this query it gave separated list for the date

```
{
        "$project": {
          "deliveryDate": {
            "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$deliveryDate" }
          },
          "counts": {
            "$multiply": [
              { "$size": "$products" },
              {
                "$sum": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

This is my document below,

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "deliveryDate": "13-03-2021",
        "products": [{
                "name": "Milk",
                "qty": 3
            },
            {
                "name": "Egg",
                "qty": 10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "deliveryDate": "13-03-2021",
        "products": [{
                "name": "Milk",
                "qty": 5
            },
            {
                "name": "Egg",
                "qty": 15
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "deliveryDate": "15-03-2021",
        "products": [{
                "name": "Milk",
                "qty": 3
            },
            {
                "name": "Egg",
                "qty": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

my expected output like this based on the date it should add the `qty` in the array should give sum of the count for the date

```
[
  {
    "deliveryDate": "13-03-2021",
    "count" : 33
  },
  {
    "deliveryDate": "15-03-2021",
    "count" : 13
  }
]
```

logic ==> get the all the document based on the date and add the quantity, calculate the count
if this possible to do with mongodb query itself
Thanks advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$sum` to get total sum of `qty` in same field `products`
- `$group` by `deliveryDate` and get sum of products quantity

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { products: { $sum: "$products.qty" } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$deliveryDate",
      count: { $sum: "$products" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/865NFDmWT2y)

Comment: yes, this is working perfectly, and performance also great